# Incrementing the max size limit of .sql file in php myadmin

Tags: php

I want to know that is there any way to increase the max file size limit of import option in php myadmin. In case of mine it is being displayed that the max file size limit is 2mb. But i downloaded a sample .sql file of a large database which is about 40 mb. Now what can i do to import that database??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open php.ini

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M 
upload_max_filesize = 2M 
max_execution_time = 30 
max_input_time = 60 
memory_limit = 8M
```

Replace:

```
post_max_size = 750M 
upload_max_filesize = 750M 
max_execution_time = 5000 
max_input_time = 5000 
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Save file & Restart services.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an issue with php.ini and your max upload is limited there.  Search php.ini for upload_max_filesize - I would bet it is at 2MB.  Change to 50 and you should be good to import.